# SQL error when i try to search in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, database, search, sql, catalogsearch

im very new to Magento, issue is when i try to search somrthing on my magento frontend its showing me error

[image]

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Seems like indexing is broken , maybe you have imported products in magento with direct mysql queries or Magmi? Try to run from ssh

> php shell/indexer.php reindexall

And try to see if reindex is working correctly